# Is it legal to rip ISOs/ROMs from physical game discs for use in a PC emulator?

Tags: copyright, germany, online-piracy

I live in Germany. I own a Wii Console and related hardware, as well as some games in the form of physical discs.

I would like to play those games (which I legally own on disk) on my PC using an emulator without downloading ROMs (game/disc images) from the internet (which is obviously illegal).

Is it possible to legally copy those discs to a PC for the purpose of playing the games in an emulator?

Comment: Questions like "_What approach should I take?_" are a big no-no on this site.

Comment: Oh sorry i copy pasted this from another stackexchange where i posted this and got redirected here which was about gaming and it was more referring to the best way to do this if it was legal. I will remove it. I edited it hope its fine now

Comment: I edited it further; hopefully this addresses the concerns about requesting legal advice.

Comment: I remember rumours about how you could watch movies online/play downloaded copies online if you legally purchased them (as in, what you bought is a license that allows you to legally watch/play it, along with a physical copy to do so). But that might just be a rumour.

Comment: I heard about that too but it seems to be that if you buy a DVD or CD or a game you own the DVD. Not the game or Video. So that would be illegal.

Answer (score 1):

1. In general, you can make private copies of works you legitimately own for non-commercial purposes, see limitation provision [§ 53 Ⅰ UrhG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0348).
   A plain [`dd(1)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) is unobjectionable.
   As soon as you need to circumvent an “effective technological measure” (e. g. a copy protection) though, [§ 95a UrhG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0723), it’s not OK anymore.
2. In your particular case:
   The disc you intend to copy contains a game.
   This is a **computer program**.
   You will need *prior authorization* to make any copy thereof, [§ 69c № 1 UrhG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0541).
   A back‑up copy is only permissible if its sole intent is *to be* a back‑up, [§ 69d Ⅱ UrhG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0547), say in the event the original optical disc itself becomes unreadable.
   You actually intend to *use* the copy on your PC though, while the original disc is still operational.
   This isn’t allowed.
3. Virtually all violations of IPR (intellectual property rights) are criminal (or administrative) offenses, [§§ 106 ff. UrhG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0842), yet like any crime, if nobody knows that *you* are committing it, you won’t experience no troubles.